# GoogleScript Spreadsheet Custom Function Handling a range of cells and getting their values

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have a Goggle Spreadsheet with some data, and I want to write a custom function to use in the sheet, which accepts a range of cells and a delimiter character, takes each cell value, splits it by the delimiter, and counts the total.

```
For example
Column A has the following values in rows 1-3: {"Sheep","Sheep,Dog","Cat"}
My function would be called like this: =CountDelimitedValues(A1:A3;",");
It should return the value: 4 (1+2+1)
```

The problem I am having is in my custom script I get errors like

> "TypeError: cannot get function GetValues from type Sheep"

This is my current script:

```
function CountArrayList(arrayList, delimiter) {
  var count = 0;
  //for (i=0; i<array.length; i++)
  //{
    //count += array[i].split(delimiter).length;
  //}

  var newArray = arrayList.GetValues();
  return newArray.ToString();

  //return count;
}
```

I understand that the parameter arraylist is receiving an array of objects from the spreadsheet, however I don't know how to get the value out of those objects, or perhaps cast them into strings.

Alternatively I might be going about this in the wrong way? I have another script which extracts the text from a cell between two characters which works fine for a single cell. What is it about a range of cells that is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this works :

```
function CountArrayList(arrayList) {
return arrayList.toString().split(',').length
}
```

wouldn't it be sufficient ?

edit Oooops, sorry I forgot the user defined delimiter, so like this

```
function CountArrayList(arrayList,del) {
return arrayList.toString().split(del).length
}
```

usage : `=CountArrayList(A1:C1;",")`

NOTE : in this example above it would be dangerous to use another delimiter than "," since the `toString()` joins the array elements with commas... if you really need to do so try using a regex to change the commas to what you use and apply the split on that.

try like this :

```
function CountArrayList(arrayList,del) {
return arrayList.toString().replace(/,/g,del).split(del).length
}
```

Comment: That works and it bothers me because I could have sworn I tried that. Or I think perhaps I tried something like arrayList[0].toString() which didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

That's something you can achieve without using script but plain old formula's:

`=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(LEN(A1:A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3; ","; "")) + 1))`

Credit goes here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37744/29140

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I have was that I needed to implicitly cast the objects in the array being passed as a string.

For example this function accepts the array of cells, and outputs their contents as a string with del as the delimiter (similar to the String.Split() function). Note the TrimString function and that it is being passed an element of the array.

```
function ArrayToString(array,del) {
  var string = "";

  for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] != null) {
      var trimmedString = TrimString(array[i]);
      if (trimmedString != "") {
        if (string.length > 0) {
          string += del;
        }

        string += trimmedString;
      }
    }
  }

  return string;
}
```

Below is the TrimString function.

```
function TrimString(string) {
  var value = "";
  if (string != "" && string != null) {
    var newString = "";
    newString += string;

    var frontStringTrimmed = newString.replace(/^\s*/,"");
    var backStringTrimmed = frontStringTrimmed.replace(/\s*$/,"");
    value = backStringTrimmed;
  }
  return value;
}
```

What I found is that this code threw a TypeError unless I included the declaration of the newString variable, and added the array element object to it, implicitly casting the array element object as a string. Otherwise the replace() functions could not be called.

Comment: Why do you want to use Google Apps Script for this? Because it is possible?

Comment: Mostly yes. The formula you presented earlier works, and actually I already had a formula similar to yours that did all of this plus more that didn't use Google Apps Script. There are some parameters to this problem that I have not completely shared. However the primary motivation was to condense the amount of code needed to be typed so that it could be re-used across the entire spreadsheet easily and quickly.